# Is this a good way of making dynamic content switching for a website? (JQUERY)

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, href

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ContentLoader").click(function(){
        $.page = $(this).attr("goto");
        $("#content").slideToggle(500, function(){
            $(this).load("/pages/"+$.page+".php", function(){
                $(this).slideToggle(500);
            });
        });

    });

});
</script>

<style>
#menu{border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px; border-radius: 7px}
#menu a{background-color: skyblue; padding: 2px 20px 2px 20px}
#content{padding: 10px; background-color: silver; border: 2px solid black; border-radius: 7px; margin-top: 5px}
</style>

<body>

<div id="menu">
    <a href="javascript:" goto="default" class="ContentLoader">Main</a>
    <a href="javascript:" goto="contact" class="ContentLoader">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:" goto="default" class="ContentLoader">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:" goto="default" class="ContentLoader">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="javascript:" goto="default" class="ContentLoader">Partners</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
    hey
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Is this a good way to make a dynamic content switcher???
Also I had to use href="javascript: " to prevent the page from loading when clicking on the link.

Could you veterans tell me if it needs to be improved?

Comment: You're opening yourself up for some pretty subjective answers, as in there is probably no one correct answer for 'is this a good way'.

Answer (score 0):

No need to put the same class name on every at tag. Just use $("#menu a")

goto is not a valid attribute. Use the new data-attributes ( http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ )

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(event){

    $("#menu a").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.page = $(this).data("goto");
        $("#content").slideToggle(500, function(){
            $(this).load("/pages/"+$.page+".php", function(){
                $(this).slideToggle(500);
            });
        });

    });

});
</script>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#default" data-goto="default">Main</a>
    <a href="#contact" data-goto="contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about" data-goto="default">About</a>
    <a href="#signup" data-goto="default">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="#Partners" data-goto="default">Partners</a>
</div>
```

use anchor in your urls, and then use event.preventDefault();
also look at http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/